# Get list of properties of an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using entity framework.

I would like to get the property list of an entity when the EntityState of the object is "Added", and loop throught them.

here is a sample code of what I'm doing.

```
var newEntities = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
foreach (var entry in newEntities)
{
    var entityName = entry.EntitySet.Name;
    var newProps = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).GetModifiedProperties();
    var currentNewValues = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).CurrentValues;

    foreach (var propName in newProps)
    {
        var newValue = currentNewValues[propName];
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use

> ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).GetModifiedProperties();

to get the property list, but It's working only when the State is EntityState.Modified.

Thanks.

**Here is the way to perform my needs**

With that, I can get all the attribute for an entity and get his value too.

```
 var newEntities = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
 foreach (var entry in newEntities)
 {
      if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
      {
           var prop = entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties();
           var entityName = entry.EntitySet.Name;

           var currentNewValues = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).CurrentValues;
           foreach (var propName in prop.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Namespace == "System"))
           {
                var newValue = currentNewValues[propName.Name];
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Which properties do you want? A list of all the (values of all the) properties of the entity class?

Comment: I just want properties int32, string,bool etc not entity class like ex("EntityObject,EntityReference"). And then get the value for these property. Ex if I have an entity Contact, I would like to get ContactID, ContactName etc...

Comment: For more clarity I need the method to return only the attributes (i.e. the name of the columns of the table) of the entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (var entry in newEntities)
{
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        // continue and get property list
        var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues;
        for (var i = 0; i < currentValues.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var fName = currentValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata[i].FieldType.Name;
            var fCurrVal = currentValues[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each entry you are enumerating over should have a 'State' property which is the EntityState, so you can either filter them out with an if clause or use linq,

```
        foreach (var entry in newEntities)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                  // continue and get property list
            }
        }
```

Or

```
        var addedEntities = newEntities.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);
```

Also I'm not sure if you need to look at 'Modified Properties' at all. If it is an entity which has only just been added then why would it have any modified properties and not simply new ones (ie CurrentValues)?

Comment: Yeah this is where is my problem. I Don't know how to get the list of properties. "Modified Properties" Return a list of modified properties and in this context, this is not the proper way to get my property list. How to do get this  list. ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It seems to me that you only need to use the .GetCurrentValues() method. The msdn documentation says that GetModifiedProperties() returns the names of an object's properties that have changed since the last time SaveChanges() was called. If its a new entity that didn't exist last time SaveChanges() was called, it won't have any modified properties.